# Create one partition occupying all the space on the drive with gparted?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd, parted

I am following the instructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive

It says:

> 4) Create one partition occupying all the space on the drive:
>
> `(parted) mkpart primary 0 0`
>
> 5) Check that the results are correct:
>
> `(parted) print`

However when I do this I get:

```
$sudo parted /dev/sda
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) mklabel gpt
(parted) unit GB
(parted) mkpart primary 0 0
(parted) print
Model: ATA Some SSD (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 240GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 1      0.00GB  0.00GB  0.00GB               primary
```

The Start and End of 0GB and Size of 0GB is making me think this isn't correct.  I would have thought the size should have been 240GB (or close to it).  Are these instructions correct? If not, what is the correct way to make a single partition that covers the entire disk?

Answer (score 20):

Using 0% for the start causes parted to automatically align the sectors for best performance:

`(parted) mkpart primary 0% 100%`

Credits to comments in article at https://rainbow.chard.org/2013/01/30/how-to-align-partitions-for-best-performance-using-parted/

PS: u could also specify the filesystem type in same command, e.g for xfs:

`(parted) mkpart primary xfs 0% 100%`

Answer (score 4):

Your mkpart line is wrong. The parameters are: partition-name, start-position and size.

In parted, run

```
`rm primary` 
`mkpart primary 2048s 100%`
```

to remove the old, wrong, partition and recreate a new that spans the whole disk.

Comment: What does `p1` and `2048s` stand for?

Comment: p1 is the partition name, you can use any name, p1, primary or what you like. 2048s is the start sector for the partiton. This is needed for some disks / disk-arrays to get proper alignment of the partiton and optimal IO performance. This post explains how to calculate this value:  https://rainbow.chard.org/2013/01/30/how-to-align-partitions-for-best-performance-using-parted/

Comment: If you are in doubt of what commands or parameters does, read the manual-page: `man parted`.

Comment: The man page on Ubuntu says the first parameter of `mkpart` is `part-type  should  be  one  of  "primary",  "logical",  or  "extended".` Is using an arbitrary name correct?

Comment: Primary / logical extended is only for MSDOS / MBR partitioning. The line I initially wrote will work, but I have changed the answer so that it matches what the manual says ;-)